# Grey state of elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a application in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. But it became Grey State of Health somehow. Now, I am facing a lot of problem to update or change configure in this environment. So, how can I make health Green from Grey?

Comment: Is impossible to provide a precise answer for your question, if not: "it depends", you should add some details (like what kind of container are you using, if you have a custom ami or not, what issues are you facing, and so on)

Comment: I have no custom ami. I can not change any type of configuration in this state (Grey). But the site is running.

Comment: did you take a look to logs snapshots? did you check if your EC2 instance is up and running properly? (console/ec2) ...if so can you ssh to that instance?

Comment: I can not check the logs snapshots. EC2 instance is up and running properly according to console. But i can not ssh to that instance because I could not add keypair in configuration and this is the main problem that I am facing. When I am going to add keypair then it show the following error: "Unable to validate settings: Environment named o****ee is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready."

Comment: you should create and define a key-pair before running your environment, in your situation I fear that you need to rebuild your environment :/

Comment: Is there any way to protect my files if i need to rebuild my environment?

Comment: your application source code should be preserved under "application versions" and you can redeploy the same app later (verify that your app is listed there), but if you rebuild the environment you have to make at least a snapshot of your database (if you left the default options, eb won't create one automatically), since beanstalk destroys all the associated services related to the environment (rds, elastic load balancer and so on)... good luck :P

Comment: I am having the same problem.  but @daveoncode, it is impossible to rebuild the environment, push code, do anything.

Comment: @Nate I was recreate a new environment and deploy the application again from preserved versions. Now I have a very clean, Green state application :)

Comment: an environment in grey means that something went wrong. Since you didn't specify any other information such as logs, this question cannot be answered here.

Comment: Try to ssh into the machine and look at some logs and running processes. For what it's worth, this happened to me because I had accidentally started a Gulp.js `watch' task on the server. I ssh'd, killed gulp, and the status became green.

Answer (score 0):

It must respond with 200 OK, [see doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html)

You can set the key pair when you are deploying, then find the public IP in the EC2 instances, connect there (see doc) and check manually.